# Error while trying to test if a specific table exists in a MySQL database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset, database-metadata

I want to check wether a table named `basestation` exists in a MySQL table from a Java program using JDBC. My code is:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();

tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "basestations", null);

if (tables.next())
{   
     //Table exists in database
     //...
}
else
{
     //Table does not exist
     //...
}
```

but although table `basestations` exists in my database it seems that my code never enters the first clause and always decides that table does not exist, causing naturally a `table already exists in database` SQL error when trying to create the table from the beginning.

Comment: Can you provide the output for `getTables(null, null, null, null);`?

Comment: What happens if you use `"BASESTATIONS"` or `"\`basestations\`"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best way to do it below.. But you could do the following:

Use JDBC to send the following statement:

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables where information_schema.table_schema='your_schema' and information_schema.table_name='basestations';
```

Parse the jdbc result set.

That should return either 1 or 0.  If the resulting count is 1, then the table exists, otherwise, it does not.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your getTables() not returning anything here. As per getTables documentation **Only table descriptions matching the catalog, schema, table name and type criteria are returned**. In your case catalog and schema are null, which may not be correct (my guess), populate them with proper values.

Comment: Read the documentation: `null` means "ignore this part of the filter".

Comment: @thinksteep: no it certainly returns something